# Exception accessing XAML controls inside a task

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, c++-cx

If I try to access XAML controls inside a task (and task::then) my Metro XAML app always stops with an exception. The same code works without any problems outside the task. I didn't find any answer - what did I miss?

VS11 Debugger reports: Concurrency::unobserved_task_exception

Exception: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.

Many thanks for your help!

```
void MyClass::MyMemberFunction()
{
    xamlStoryboard->Stop(); // ok
    xamlImage->Source = ref new BitmapImage(); // ok

    task<void> atask([this] ()
    {
        xamlStoryboard->Stop(); // exception!
        xamlImage->Source = ref new BitmapImage(); //exception!
    });

    atask.then([this] ()
    {
        xamlStoryboard->Stop(); // exception!
        xamlImage->Source = ref new BitmapImage(); //exception!
    });
}
```

The atask.then() continuation code runs without exception if we add task_continuation_context::use_current()
as second parameter:

```
    atask.then([this] ()
    {
        xamlStoryboard->Stop(); // now ok!
        xamlImage->Source = ref new BitmapImage(); // now ok!
    }, task_continuation_context::use_current());
```

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Comment: Question updated - VS11 Debugger reports: Concurrency::unobserved_task_exception

Comment: That didn't say much, does it have an inner exception?

Comment: Try invoking that on the Dispatcher thread, if there is any.

Comment: Exception: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling your UI elements from a thread other than the UI/Dispatcher thread. You need to call your UI elements' methods using control.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync() or otherwise make sure you are not calling them from a background thread.

Comment: Thanks, for the explanation. 
I found: Creating Asynchronous Operations in C++ for Metro style Apps
Chapter: "Controlling the Execution Thread" for more details.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750082(v=vs.110).aspx

But I further don't unterstand, why I get exceptions in the task::then continuation code. I thought task::then is the callback code executed after the task finishes and runs in the main thread with access to UI/XAML controls?

Comment: Answered in MSDN: 
If you pass task_continuation_context::use_current() as a second parameter to the 'then' method then your callback will be scheduled as expected without needing to use the Dispatcher.
 
For further info see Asynchronous programming in C++ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780559.aspx about 2/3 of the way down in 'Managing the thread context'.